# Is there an automated tool for generating script sharp libraries?

Tags: script#

I can't believe all that code for jQuery was done by hand.

Edit. Just to be cleaeer

Script # has a set of libraries that wrap jquery. This allows me to call jquery functions in natural c# way. But they are large long winded. But they also look neat and consistent. Looks like a tool generated them. But there is no tool in the scripts arp package. Hence the q

Comment: You need to make your question more clear. :)

Comment: The man who knows the answer understood the question but I will clarify it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no magic tool... and I did hand-write the jQuery code.

If you look at it you'll see one really has to look at all the "quirks" ... ummm ... features accomplished by varying parameter sequences/counts etc. to get different behaviors, as well as the possible different return values etc. All of this information is simply not there in the script to be able to create a nice wrapper.

Furthermore there are places where you have to think about what a natural/useful c# experience will be ... for example, use of enums to represent string literals, numeric literals. How to represent different behaviors as overloads or differently named c# APIs that translate to same call at runtime. Same goes for where some generics would be useful.

Its not rocket science, but requires a bit of work. It also depends on the size of the API you're trying to wrap. jQuery core is a fairly large surface area, compared to other jQuery plugins.

Comment: Iwas hoping to wrap dojo. V big. I see that sharp kit seems to have a wrapper generator  maybe I can modify that

Comment: Do let me know if you hit questions, and/or want to bounce ideas in creating a Dojo wrapper. I think it would be a useful addition for some. Hopefully the wrapper generator can provide a reasonable start.

Comment: Did you manage to get somewhere with the dojo library generation? The new API looks very much like something that could be easily wrapped... It doesn't use global variables, any luck there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I'm getting your question right, but are you looking for a code generation for jQuery ? If so, I don't think there are. However, there are great plugins that you can use with free software such as Aptana Studio. Hope it helps :)